# how can I write the lisp function to use the predicate

Tags: common-lisp

for example, what should I input is here finfirst #'oddp '(1 2 3), and it should find the first odd number return to the list, so what I think I need to do is to write a function just have one argument which is list, but I only know to find the first element in the list, so how can I use the condition in my code

```
 (defun finfirst(list)(cond((null list) nil)
```

if I finish this, then it will told me that I need two argument， I just don't know what should I do for this function, just give me some hint for that

Comment: What are you having problems with? Adding more parameters to the parameter list? Using a variable bound function? Please **edit** your question with more precise description of your problem.

Comment: it told me to find the first element in a list which is satisfying the predicate in the list or return nil if the list is null, but I just don't know how can I set the predicate in my code

Comment: [`funcall`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_funcal.htm)? eg. `(defun test-element (predicate element) (funcall predicate element)) (test-element #'oddp 1) ; ==> t`

Comment: yeah I think so maybe, but it should like (finfirst #'odd (1 2 3))means to find the first odd element will return 1, also it will have another limit condition like (finfirst #'characterp '(1 2 3 4 #\a) it will return other thing

Comment: Yes, but if you have the element bound to the variable `element` you cani easily change it from returning the result of the predicate to the element you passed to the argument? You know, with `if`?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the functionality you described, you can use the function find-if, eg:

```
(find-if #'oddp '(1 2 3))
```

If you want to implement it yourself, you could do something like this:

```
(defun finfirst (function list)
  (cond
    ((null list) nil)
    ((funcall function (first list)) (first list))
    (t (finfirst function (rest list)))))
```

Then use it like this:

```
(finfirst #'oddp '(1 2 3))
```